# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [foo] and [bar] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/url] which is not permitted

Tags: tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception, url-pattern, servlet-mapping

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [JavaQuestionForm] and [JavaQuestion] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/JavaQuestion] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2443)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJndi(ContextConfig.java:2041)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1948)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I already did many stuffs to resolve this issue...As I removed the Tmp folder.But I got the same result..                                                                  In the second attempt, I installed a new tomcat but again same result...

Answer (score 2):

As said by the exception, you are trying to bind 2 differents servlet to the same URI :

```
The servlets named [JavaQuestionForm] and [JavaQuestion] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/JavaQuestion] which is not permitted
```

You have to change your `web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check your `web.xml` or web config annotations. Apparently you mapped two different servlets (`JavaQuestion` and `JavaQuestionForm`) to the same URL: `/JavaQuestion`.